# Why are my nested route components not rendering in react-router-dom 6?

Tags: javascript

I have the following routes in my App.tsx file:

When I visit the `/help` URL, I can see that the document title and navbar have loaded in the DOM, however, I don't see any of my nested routes and I'm also not receiving any errors or warnings.

Comment: What are the errors or warnings?

Comment: @Jacobo I'm not receiving any errors or warning.

Comment: one thing to note is that your `/collections` path inside the `Collections` component is rendering a `Collections` component, its maybe referring to itself?

Comment: @andymccullough That's a different Collections component.

Comment: I don't see any overt issues with the code you've shared. Can you create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: "That's a different Collections component." - Uh, how do you disambiguate that one from the `Collections` component rendering it? Can you share a more complete code example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Place this code to the last item instead <Route path="/collections" element={<Collections />} /> right after <Route path="/collections/addItems/:collectionId" element={<ManageCollectionItems />} />

Comment: @DrewReese I edited my code to the real thing. I changed it a bit for the example, but I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Can you clarify what "I don't see any of my nested routes" means when you are on the `"/collections"` path? If you were on that path I'd expect to only see `<Route path="/collections" element={<Collections />} />` rendered. Do you mean navigating to the other routes isn't working? Is there an issue in the way you link to your other routes in `Navbar`? Can we see that component?

Comment: the only other thing I can think of is that your top level `Routes` is taking care of the `/collections` part of the URL, therefore the nested routes also having `/collections` would make me wonder if router is expecting your URL to be `/collections/collections`

Comment: I expected that when I'm on /collections , I'd see the Root component rendered and that the Root component itself will render the Collections component by default because the Collections component is set to be rendered on /collections path. Maybe I'm not understanding how react-router-dom 6 handles these things.

Comment: nested routes changed quite a bit in v6, here's a nice guide that explains it - https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-router-nested-routes/ I dont believe you are following that nesting pattern at the minute and are more aligned to the 'v5' way of doing it

Comment: @andymccullough Ah you're right, it was expecting the URL to be /collections/collections. After removing the /collections from every nested route, it started working. Thanks a lot! You can put it as an answer if you want so I can select it as the correct one!

Comment: Your "nested" routes are using absolute paths, so I'm still thinking your `Navbar` is part of the issue, considering you are passing a `baseUrl="/collections"` prop to them.... I'm suspecting your `Navbar` may be using relative paths and prepending this `baseUrl` value to them, similar to how RRDv5 needed the `path` and `url` from `match` to build up nested routes and links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your top level Routes is taking care of the `/collections` part of the URL, therefore the nested routes also having `/collections` would make me wonder if router is expecting your URL to be `/collections/collections`